# localStorage.setItem(key, val) showing undefiend

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-local-storage

I am trying to set my object locally and i console.log that localstorage but i am getting undefined.

here is my function

```
            searchBar(item) { //item is object here as parameter

             console.log(item);
        localStorage.setItem('object',JSON.stringify(item))
this.quickOrder.push(localStorage.getItem('object'));

    console.log(this.quickOrder);

                  }
```

i have a quickOrder Array declared globaly.

in my console.log(item) i am able to see my object.

i am trying to push that object with local storage to my empty array so that i can make use of ngFor to display in UI.

> my console.log(this.quciOrder); shows undefiend.

Comment: If `quickOrder` is declared globally - as you say - what's with the `this` usage? Perhaps you should include more code in the question.

Comment: since it is declared gloablly on the class so to make use of the array inside a function we should use this key word to access it

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `LocalStorage` from `Ionic`? If not, I think it would be better if you use it because it makes things easier (please notice that LocalStorage storage engine uses the browser's local storage system for storing key/value pairs, so it would be the same in terms of where is that data being stored). Just like you can see in [LocalStorage docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/LocalStorage/) you can initialize it like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage, LocalStorage } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  template: `<ion-content></ion-content>`
});
export class MyClass{
 constructor(){
   this.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
 }
}
```

And then use the `get(key)` and `set(key, value)` methods, but keeping in mind that both methods return a **promise** so you should do

```
searchBar(item) { //item is object here as parameter

  console.log(item);

  this.local.set('object',JSON.stringify(item)).then(() => {

    // Code to execute after the value is set in the LocalStorage...

  });

  // Or

  this.local.get('object').then((data) => {

    // Code to execute after the value is get from the LocalStorage...
    this.quickOrder.push(data);

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to JSON.parse the localStorage data before pushing in array. `localStorage.setItem('object',JSON.stringify(item));`
`this.quickOrder.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('object')));`